# Label four equations on one line

Tags: cross-referencing, align

I have an equation in an `align` environment that I wrote as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[pdfencoding = auto, psdextra, bookmarksdepth = 4]{hyperref}%        
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}%  http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref   
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\text{other stuff} & = \\ 
m_{eq}\ddot{y}_i                                                                     
  &= k_{eq}\Bigl[y_i + \frac{m_{eq}}{m_b}\sum_jy_j\Bigr] +                      
     c\Bigl[\dot{y}_i + \frac{m_{eq}}{m_b}\sum_j\dot{y}_j\Bigr] - m_{eq}gy_i +  
     F_i(t)  
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The second equation is really four different equations since `i = 1, 2, 3, 4` but it is only labeled as one equation. Is there anyway to have it labeled as four equations and still be reference? I know I could say `\tag{(10), (11), (12), (13)}` but it doesn't look right. If I list them all separately and reference them, LaTeX writes equations (10) to (13).

Is there an optimal or way to do this?

[image]

I also just noticed that using `\tag` to number the equation as four in one messes up the numbering since LaTeX will still leave off at the last number prior to the use of `\tag`

---

PS

I know there is a typo and it says with four only four. I am to lazy to take another screen grab.

Comment: i'm probably being pedantic, but i really see only one equation, that is, only a single sign of relation.  what i see is four separate elements on the right-hand side.  is there perhaps another way of expressing this, or do you xref them separately elsewhere?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I am sorry but I don't understand what you are asking. Could you perhaps re-phrase it?

Comment: barbara explained to you that your equation is in fact only one that uses the parameter 'i' and you should reference to it as one.

Comment: @Ruben there is in fact a j. When i = 1, we run the sum through j = 1,..., 4 so when. As i indexes, we pick up equations 2, 3, and 4

Comment: I'd simply say “equation 10 for i=1” or “equation 10 for i=3”. Would you consider infinitely many labels for `f(x)=kx`?

Comment: So, in fact there are 16 equations?

Comment: @Ruben no there are 4.

Comment: @egreg is that normal to do?

Comment: Well, you insisted on the meaning of `j`. And if `i` and `j` both are integer parameters from 1 to 4, you have 16 equations. This is just basic combinatorics. In my eyes `j` is only a summation index and irrelevant to your problem regarding TeX. So, `i` is your only parameter generating multiple equations.

Comment: What @egreg said is what you do normally and what I proposed in the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @Ruben try writing out the equations if you need to prove to yourself there are only 4. They key is that the sum on j is built into i so i = 1 has (y_1 + meq/mb(y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4) + ... That is only equation. Then set i = 2.

Comment: This is basically what I am saying and what I did in the first part of my answer!

Comment: I presume that an advantage of indexing your variables is that you don't have to refer to (what you are calling) equation 10 or 11 separately.  So although this is an interesting problem I feel like it doesn't contribute to better math writing.  Why not just let it be labeled (10) and write “If we plug equations [note plural] (10) into (9), we get ...”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too big for a comment... perhaps you're after something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[pdfencoding = auto, psdextra, bookmarksdepth = 4]{hyperref}%        
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}%  http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref   
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \text{other stuff} & = \\ 
  m_{eq}\ddot{y}_i                                                                     
    &= k_{eq}\Bigl[y_i + \frac{m_{eq}}{m_b}\sum_jy_j\Bigr] +                      
       c\Bigl[\dot{y}_i + \frac{m_{eq}}{m_b}\sum_j\dot{y}_j\Bigr] - m_{eq}gy_i +  
       F_i(t)
       \tag{(\ref*{eq:A}),(\ref*{eq:B}),(\ref*{eq:C}),(\ref*{eq:D})}\label{eq:ABCD}
\end{align}
\refstepcounter{equation}\label{eq:A}%
\refstepcounter{equation}\label{eq:B}%
\refstepcounter{equation}\label{eq:C}%
\refstepcounter{equation}\label{eq:D}%
See~\ref{eq:ABCD}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: The refstepcounter will keep the lableing indexed properly too, correct (for any new equations after this one)?

Comment: @dustin: Yes. You can now also refer to the question components individually. To avoid nested hyperlinks, I've used `\ref*` and added the surrounding `(..)` manually.

Answer (score 2):

You mention in a comment on another answer that you're looking to save space. I therefore suggest you express your set of second-order differential equations in **y** using *vector notation*, say along the lines shown below. (If you don't like bold symbols for vectors, you are of course free to choose any other notational convention for vectors.)

[image]

Note that since this is a vector-valued equation, there's only one equation number. I think this is clearer than having four equation number strewn about.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto,
            psdextra,
            colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
Let 
$\bm{y}=[\begin{matrix} y_1 & y_2 & y_3 & y_4 \end{matrix}{]}'$, 
$\bm{F}(t)=[\begin{matrix} F_1(t) & F_2(t) & F_3(t) & F_4(t) \end{matrix}{]}'$, and
$d = (m_{eq}/m_b)\sum_jy_j$. We have
\begin{equation} \label{eq:yvector}
m_{eq}\ddot{\bm{y}}
  = k_{eq}[\bm{y} + d] +                      
     c[\dot{\bm{y}} + d] - m_{eq}g\bm{y} +  
     \bm{F}(t)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the multiple reference as you descdibed is reasonable if you have more than one equation. In this case you could split your equations up and use the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto,psdextra,bookmarksdepth=4]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\eqnsref}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\process{\def\process{,}}
  \def\do{\process\eqref}
  (\docsvlist{#1})
  \endgroup}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:a}
m_{eq}y_1
  = k_{eq}\Bigl[y_1 + \frac{m_{eq}}{m_b}\sum_jy_j\Bigr] +                      
     c\Bigl[\dot{y}_1 + \frac{m_{eq}}{m_b}\sum_j\dot{y}_j\Bigr] - m_{eq}gy_1 +  
     F_1(t)  
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:b}
m_{eq}y_2
  = k_{eq}\Bigl[y_2 + \frac{m_{eq}}{m_b}\sum_jy_j\Bigr] +                      
     c\Bigl[\dot{y}_2 + \frac{m_{eq}}{m_b}\sum_j\dot{y}_j\Bigr] - m_{eq}gy_2 +  
     F_2(t)  
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:c}
m_{eq}y_3
  = k_{eq}\Bigl[y_3 + \frac{m_{eq}}{m_b}\sum_jy_j\Bigr] +                      
     c\Bigl[\dot{y}_3 + \frac{m_{eq}}{m_b}\sum_j\dot{y}_j\Bigr] - m_{eq}gy_3 +  
     F_3(t)  
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:d}
m_{eq}y_4
  = k_{eq}\Bigl[y_4 + \frac{m_{eq}}{m_b}\sum_jy_j\Bigr] +                      
     c\Bigl[\dot{y}_4 + \frac{m_{eq}}{m_b}\sum_j\dot{y}_j\Bigr] - m_{eq}gy_4 +  
     F_4(t)  
\end{equation}

\eqnsref{eq:a,eq:b,eq:c,eq:d}
\end{document}
```

If you compress the equations using the parameter `i` which can be useful too (for saving space and paper) you should really just use one label and refernece to it as: "If we plus equation (x) *for* i=1,2,3,4 into (y), we get that (y) is zero."

Comment: I am looking to save space not split it up.

Comment: @dustin, the comment in the bottom of the answer is the clue! (see the comments to your OP)